# Считывание из файла , fread C

Tags: c

В классе нужны функции сохранения в файл и загрузка с файла. Сохранение в файл работает без проблем:

```
system("cls");
char filename[MAX_PATH] = "Contacts.txt";
FILE *f1 = nullptr;
fopen_s(&f1, filename, "wb");
if (f1 == NULL)
{
    perror("Error: ");
    _getch();
    return;
}
fwrite(&count, sizeof(count), 1, f1);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fwrite(pSt[i]->getName(), sizeof(pSt[i]->getName()), 1, f1);

    fwrite(pSt[i]->getSurname(), sizeof(pSt[i]->getSurname()), 1, f1);

    int a = pSt[i]->getAge();

    fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, f1);

    fwrite(pSt[i]->getPhone(), sizeof(pSt[i]->getPhone()), 1, f1);

    double b = pSt[i]->getAverage();

    fwrite(&b, sizeof(double), 1, f1);

}
RussianMessage("Успешно сохранено!\n");
_getch();
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать теперь загрузку с файла.

Comment: Читать файл в переменные, потом устанавливать поля класса по этим переменным. Или я чего-то недопонял в вопросе? Тем более что никаких "функций в классе" (то есть методов) для записи у вас нет.

Comment: `sizeof(pSt[i]->getName())` а это как понимать? Что возвращает метод `getName()`?

Comment: Метод  возвращает значение поля класса  
     
char* getName()
 {
  return name;
 }

Comment: [С]? Если это С, то что тако `nullptr`??? Что такое `pSt[i]->getPhone()`? `pSt[i]->getName()`? Указатели на функции внутри структуры?

Comment: @Костя Мазур: "Метод возвращает значение поля класса..."? В языке С нет классов и методов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, вы неправильно пишете. Вот это (если `getName()` возвращает `char *`) запишет в файл мусор. То есть не саму строку, а `sizeof(char*)` первых её символов:

```
fwrite(pSt[i]->getName(), sizeof(pSt[i]->getName()), 1, f1);
```

Вот когда разберётесь с записью, тогда можно будет и о чтении подумать, исходя из того, что именно будет записано.

Можно, например, сделать вообще как-то так:

```
struct
{
   char name[NAME_MAX];
   char surname[SURNAME_MAX];
   int age;
   char phone[PHONE_MAX];
   double avg;
} data;

strcpy( data.name, obj->getName() );
strcpy( data.surname, obj->getSurname() );
data.age = obj->getAge();
strcpy( data.phone, obj->getPhone() );
data.avg = obj->getAverage();

fwrite( &data, sizeof(data), 1, f1 );
```

И потом последовательно читать структуры, устанавливая поля объектов по их данным. Но это не лучший вариант, так как платформенно-зависимый (из-за чисел).

Или так (если в строках нет пробелов):

```
fprintf( f1, "%s %s %d %s %f\n", 
             obj->getName(), obj->getSurname(),             
             obj->getAge(), obj->getPhone(),
             obj->getAverage() );
```

И:

```
fscanf( f1, "%s %s %d %s %f\n", 
            data.name, data.surname, &data.age, data.phone, &data.avg );
```